How to prevent <dialog> to close with Esc key
The HTML element <dialog> is intended to always be closed when you press Esc key according to documentation. The problem with that is that you might want it not to close immediately, i.e. if you need to ask for user confirmation etc.
For test purposes, let's assume we have a variable preventClosing that will determine whether we want the user to be able to close the dialog with Esc button or not.
The dialog provides the event cancel, and indeed it cancel the dialog closing, but only for the first time; if you press Esc twice, it will be closed, regardless of the event.preventDefault() call as you can test on the following snippet.


const preventClosing = true;
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    dialog.showModal();
});

dialog.addEventListener('cancel', (event) => {
    if (preventClosing) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
<button>Open modal</button>
<dialog>A dialog I don't want to close with Esc</dialog>




So the way to actually fix this is not using the cancel event, but rather the keydown, as such:


const preventClosing = true;
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    dialog.showModal();
});

dialog.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Escape' && preventClosing) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
<button>Open modal</button>
<dialog>A dialog I don't want to close with Esc</dialog>



As you can see now it really does not close, regardless of how many times you press Esc.

Since your self-answered question appears a duplicate of this, you might consider adding your answer to the existing question.

Thanks @devlincarnate, just posted there as an answer.
